# add write access to user ubuntu - shared folder cifs-utils

Tags: linux, ubuntu, command-line

I have folder in /media on ubuntu - shared from windows via fstab and cifs-utils. Can I share this folder to other user: "miki" (not root). It works only for root now.

```
root@localhost:/media#
drwxr-xrwx  4 root    root 4096 Nov 15 12:21 .
drwxr-xr-x 23 root    root 4096 Nov 14 06:34 ..
drwxr-xr-x  2 padm    root    0 Nov 15 09:34 Archive
drwxr-xrwx  2 root    root 4096 Feb 25  2019 kekik
```

I have try with:

```
root@localhost:~# sudo chmod -R 757 /media/Archive/
```

but get:

```
chmod: changing permissions of '/media/Archive/': Permission denied
```

Fstab

```
//windowsServer/Archive /media/Archive  cifs  username=wundowsuser,password=somepass,uid=1000,iocharset=iso8859-1,vers=1.0  0  0
```

Comment: As `root` there is no need for a `sudo` unless you explicitly want to run a command as some user (which is not `root`). That said, please add your `fstab` entry and the cifs-line. I understand you have a windows server and access a directory there? Simplest might be to set the group to a non-root group and add the second user to that group

Answer (score 0):

Find a solution:
need to modify /etc/fstab by changing:

```
//windowsServer/Archive /media/Archive  cifs  username=wundowsuser,password=somepass,uid=1000,iocharset=iso8859-1,rw,file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777,vers=1.0  0  0
```

and change group of folder (must umont it first!)

```
sudo umount -l /media/Archive
sudo chown miki:miki /media/Archive/
```